# How to render it using react js

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

Currently, I'm able to render the posts on screen but how can I render using the select dropdown where the user can select different sort options like title, author, and description, and the posts get sorted accordingly? What should I change in order for it works any suggestions will be much appreciated. I have added both HomePage.js and Post.js which I'm using.

//HomePage.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";
        import Post from "../../Components/Post/Post";
        import "./HomePage.css";
        import axios from "axios";
        
        const HomePage = () => {
          const [posts, setPosts] = useState("");
        
          let config = { Authorization: "..................." };
          const url = "........................";
        
          useEffect(() => {
            AllPosts();
          }, []);
        
          const AllPosts = () => {
            axios
              .get(`${url}`, { headers: config })
        
              .then((response) => {
                const allPosts = response.data.articles;
                setPosts(allPosts);
                console.log(response);
              })
              .catch((error) => console.error(`Error: ${error}`));
          };
        
          const newPostsByTitle = useMemo(() => {
            return [...posts].sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title));
          }, [posts]);
        
          console.log("sorted by title", newPostsByTitle);
        
          const newPostsByAuthor = useMemo(() => {
            return [...posts].sort((a, b) => a.author.localeCompare(b.author));
          }, [posts]);
        
          console.log("sorted by author", newPostsByAuthor);
        
          const newPostsByDescription = useMemo(() => {
            return [...posts].sort((a, b) =>
              a.description.localeCompare(b.description)
            );
          }, [posts]);
        
          console.log("sorted by description", newPostsByDescription);
        
          return (
            <div className="home">
              <div className="select">
                <select
                  name="slct"
                  id="slct"
                  onChange={(e) => AllPosts(e.target.value)}
                >
                  <option value="Title">Title</option>
                  <option value="Author">Author</option>
                  <option value="Description">Description</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <Post className="Posts" posts={posts} key={posts.title} />
            </div>
          );
        };
        
        export default HomePage;
```

//Post.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./Post.css";
import { Fragment } from "react";

const Post = (props) => {
  const displayPosts = (props) => {
    const { posts } = props;

    if (posts.length > 0) {
      return posts.map((post) => {
        return (
          <Fragment>
            <div className="Post" key={post.title}>
              <img
                src={post.urlToImage}
                alt="covid"
                width="100%"
                className="img"
              />
              <h5 className="title"> {post.title}</h5>
              <p className="author"> {post.author}</p>
              <p className="description"> {post.description}</p>
            </div>
          </Fragment>
        );
      });
    }
  };
  return <div className="Posts">{displayPosts(props)}</div>;
};

export default Post;
```

Comment: By virtue of asking "What should I change in order for it works" are you saying your code isn't working and there's an issue? Can you update your question and clearly describe what the issue is? I suggest storing the select's "filter" value in state and use an inline sort when passing the posts array as a prop to `Post` (*should probably be renamed to `Posts`* ) component.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, It's not working properly. It renders allPosts but when I try to sort based on title, author, description. It's not rendering according to the changes in the sorting. I will rename it to Posts thanks for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You don't actually call `newPostsByTitle`, `newPostsByAuthor`, or `newPostsByDescription` anywhere and capture the returned sorted posts array.

## Suggestion

I suggest storing the selected sort value in state and doing an inline sort of the `posts` state when passing it to the child component.

```
const HomePage = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState("");
  const [sortBy, setSortBy] = useState("none"); // <-- add sortBy state

  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    AllPosts();
  }, []);

  const AllPosts = () => {
    ...
  };

  return (
    <div className="home">
      <div className="select">
        <select
          name="slct"
          id="slct"
          onChange={(e) => setSortBy(e.target.value)}
        >
          <option value="title">Title</option> // <-- lowercase value to match property
          <option value="author">Author</option>
          <option value="description">Description</option>
          <option value="none">No Sort</option> // <-- add no sort option
        </select>
      </div>
      <Posts
        className="Posts"
        posts={
          sortBy === "none" // <-- conditionally sort by property
            ? posts
            : posts.sort((a, b) => a[sortBy].localeCompare(b[sortBy]))
        }
        key={posts.title}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

If you don't need or want the "no sort" option then just provide one of `"title"`, `"name"`, or `"description"` as the initial `sortBy` state value and forego the ternary check and just do the sort.

## Update

Sounds like you need to use the `useMemo` hook by some external requirement. Basically move the ternary logic into the hook with a dependency on `sortBy` state and pass the memoized value to the `Posts` component's `posts` prop.

```
const sortedPosts = useMemo(() => {
  return sortBy === "none"
    ? posts
    : posts.sort((a, b) => a[sortBy].localeCompare(b[sortBy]))
}, [sortBy]);

...

<Posts
  className="Posts"
  posts={sortedPosts}
  key={posts.title}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Drew. I really appreciate it. It's working accordingly. I was struggling to call newPostsByTitle, newPostsByAuthor, or newPostsByDescription with useMemo as useMemo was one of the requirements in it to be used.

Comment: @sud Are you saying you've some requirement to use `useMemo` in your component or am I just misunderstand something? Is your question/issue resolved since you say it's working?

Comment: Yes, It's working accordingly the posts get rendered as they are sorted.

 I have the requirement of using useMemo in the component so I used it and tried to call the function and render but I was no able to do so.

Comment: It's an external requirement that I need to use useMemo in it. Is it possible for you to suggest using useMemo Yes sure I will mark it as an accepted answer and upvote as well.

Comment: @sud Ah, ok... I added an update for you then, should be very close for your requirement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231840/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-sud).